# In Java, how could I make a letter flash on the screen depending on a BPM value the user provides?

Tags: java, swing, business-process-management

With Swing, I've created a window and want a letter to flash on the screen depending on the BPM (Beats per minute) the user inputs, and I was wondering how I would go about timing the flashing accurately. I tried using a Swing Timer but it is not very accurate and I see a lot of pauses or lag. I've heard something about using `System.nanoTime()` and `System.currentTimeMillis()` but have no clue how to implement them to create a timer. Any help would be appreciated!

Note.java

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Note extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

JPanel mainScreen = new JPanel();
JPanel south = new JPanel();
JPanel north = new JPanel();

//emptyNumberMain = how many empty panels you want to use
public int emptyNumberMain = 2;
JPanel[] emptyMain = new JPanel[emptyNumberMain];

JLabel title = new JLabel("Fretboard Trainer!");
JButton start = new JButton("Start!");

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Note();
}

public Note() {
    super("Random Note!");
    setSize(300,300);
    setResizable(false);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    //creates emptyNumberMain amount of empty panels
    for (int i = 0; i < emptyNumberMain; i++) {
        emptyMain[i] = new JPanel();
    }


    mainScreen.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    south.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,1));
    south.add(emptyMain[0]);
    south.add(start);
    south.add(emptyMain[1]);

    north.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,2));
    north.add(title);

    title.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
    title.setFont(title.getFont().deriveFont(32f)); 
    start.addActionListener(this);

    mainScreen.add(north, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    mainScreen.add(south, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    add(mainScreen);
    setVisible(true);
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if (e.getSource() == start) {
        dispose();
        new RandomNote();
    }
}
}
```

RandomNote.java

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.JSlider;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class RandomNote extends JFrame {

    JPanel noteScreen = new JPanel();
    JPanel center = new JPanel();
    JPanel southSlider = new JPanel();
    JLabel bpm = new JLabel();
    //emptyNumber = how many empty panels you want to use
    int emptyNumber = 2;
    JPanel[] empty = new JPanel[emptyNumber];

    JLabel rndNote = new JLabel();
    JSlider slider = new JSlider(0,200,100);

    Timer timer2 = new Timer(100, new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            bpm.setText(Integer.toString(slider.getValue()));
            timer.setDelay((int) ((60.0/slider.getValue()) * 1000));
        }
    }); 
    public RandomNote() {   
        super("Random Notes!");
        timer.start();
        timer2.start();
        setSize(500,500);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setResizable(false);

        //creates variable emptyNumber amount of empty panels
        for (int i = 0; i < emptyNumber; i++) {
            empty[i] = new JPanel();
        }

        noteScreen.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        center.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,1));
        center.add(rndNote);

        southSlider.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,1));
        slider.setLabelTable(slider.createStandardLabels(20));
        slider.setPaintTicks(true);
        slider.setPaintLabels(true);
        slider.setMinorTickSpacing(5);
        slider.setMajorTickSpacing(20);
        southSlider.add(slider);
        southSlider.add(bpm);

        rndNote.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        rndNote.setFont(rndNote.getFont().deriveFont(32f));


        noteScreen.add(center, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        noteScreen.add(southSlider, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        add(noteScreen);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    Timer timer = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            rndNote.setText(noteOutput());
        }
    });

     public static String noteOutput() {
        Random rand = new Random();
        String[] note = {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G"};
        int randNum = rand.nextInt(7);
        return note[randNum];
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide your code as a runnable example([SSCCE](http://sscce.org)), so we also can see what's wrong.

Comment: @lexicore - saving that link. Thanks.

Comment: Ah I see I'm very sorry! First time posting my mistake. Added my code now.

Comment: *"I see a lot of pauses or lag. I've heard something about using System.nanoTime() and System.currentTimeMillis()"* - It likely won't make any difference as the "lag" is probably coming for the EDT, so any other solution, which will need to sync updates to the UI through the EDT will likely suffer from the same issues.

Answer (score 1):

The immediate thing that jumps out at me is this...

```
Timer timer2 = new Timer(100, new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        bpm.setText(Integer.toString(slider.getValue()));
        timer.setDelay((int) ((60.0/slider.getValue()) * 1000));
    }
});
```

Why do you need to update the text and reset the timer every 100 milliseconds?

So, the simple answer would be to use a `ChangeListener` on the `JSlider` to determine when the slider's value changes.  I'd recommend having a look at [How to Use Sliders](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/slider.html) for more details

As a runnable concept...

```
import java.awt.AlphaComposite;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.Icon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JSlider;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }

    public Main() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private AnimatableLabel label;

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
            gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
            label = new AnimatableLabel("BMP");
            label.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
            add(label, gbc);
            label.start();

            JSlider slider = new JSlider(10, 200);
            slider.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
                    label.setBPM(slider.getValue());
                }
            });
            slider.setValue(60);

            add(slider, gbc);
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

    }

    public class AnimatableLabel extends JLabel {

        private Timer pulseTimer;
        private Timer fadeTimer;

        private double bpm = 60;
        private double alpha = 0;
        private Long pulsedAt;

        public AnimatableLabel(String text, Icon icon, int horizontalAlignment) {
            super(text, icon, horizontalAlignment);
            setBackground(Color.RED);
            initTimer();
        }

        public AnimatableLabel(String text, int horizontalAlignment) {
            super(text, horizontalAlignment);
            setBackground(Color.RED);
            initTimer();
        }

        public AnimatableLabel(String text) {
            super(text);
            setBackground(Color.RED);
            initTimer();
        }

        public AnimatableLabel(Icon image, int horizontalAlignment) {
            super(image, horizontalAlignment);
            setBackground(Color.RED);
            initTimer();
        }

        public AnimatableLabel(Icon image) {
            super(image);
            setBackground(Color.RED);
            initTimer();
        }

        public AnimatableLabel() {
            setBackground(Color.RED);
            initTimer();
        }

        public void start() {
            updateTimer();
        }

        public void stop() {
            pulseTimer.stop();
            fadeTimer.stop();
        }

        protected void initTimer() {
            pulseTimer = new Timer((int)(getDuration()), new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    pulsedAt = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    alpha = 1.0;
                    repaint();
                }
            });
            pulseTimer.setInitialDelay(0);
            pulseTimer.setCoalesce(true);

            fadeTimer = new Timer(5, new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    if (pulsedAt == null) {
                        return;
                    }

                    long fadingDuration = System.currentTimeMillis() - pulsedAt;                
                    alpha = 1.0 - (fadingDuration / getDuration());
                    if (alpha > 1.0) {
                        alpha = 1.0;
                    } else if (alpha < 0.0) {
                        alpha = 0.0;
                    }
                    repaint();
                }
            });
            fadeTimer.setCoalesce(true);
        }

        protected double getDuration() {
            return (60.0 / bpm) * 1000.0;
        }

        protected void updateTimer() {
            fadeTimer.stop();
            pulseTimer.stop();
            pulseTimer.setDelay((int)getDuration());

            pulseTimer.start();
            fadeTimer.start();
        }

        public void setBPM(double bpm) {
            this.bpm = bpm;
            setText(Double.toString(bpm));
            updateTimer();
        }

        public double getBPM() {
            return bpm;
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            g2d.setComposite(AlphaComposite.SrcOver.derive((float)alpha));
            g2d.setColor(Color.RED);
            g2d.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
            g2d.dispose();
            super.paintComponent(g);
        }

    }
}
```